# Regex "All that don't contain this string"

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am not at all familiar with, nor have I ever had to really use regex before. I'm using some software that requires regex for "advanced filters" and I've spent the better part of 2 hours researching & trying to get this to work... I've found other posts that seem similar, but for the life of me, I cannot adapt those answers to my specific need.

Requirement: Return all results which DO NOT contain a permutation of:

```
ListView
List View
Listview
List view
listview
list view
listView
list View
```

...but would need to match anything else with more than 0 characters. I've gotten the following to work in the positive case (e.g. it successfully *matches* the strings above. Now I just need to negate it.

```
[Ll]ist[\s]?[Vv]iew
```

Intuitively, this seems like it should be easy... Things I've tried:

```
(?![Ll]ist[\s]?[Vv]iew)
(?!([Ll]ist[\s]?[Vv]iew))
(?:(?!([Ll]ist[\s]?[Vv]iew)))
```

Comment: Your initial regex matches `listView` which is not included in your 5 words

Comment: @Carpsen90 Thanks, it was non-exhaustive (any permutation). But I've updated it either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one pattern which seems to work:

```
^(?!.*\b[Ll]ist[ ]?[Vv]iew\b).*$
```

### Demo

It uses a negative lookahead to assert that no permutation of `list` + `view` occurs.  You were on the right track, but the general pattern to assert that some word `WORD` does not occur anywhere is this:

```
^(?!.*\bWORD\b)
```

The `.*` allows for `WORD` to occur anywhere.

Note that if you regex tool has a case insensitive mode, then the pattern can be simplified to this:

```
^(?!.*\blist[ ]?view\b).*$
```

Comment: Thanks, when I type that into https://www.regexpal.com/ it doesn't appear to match any of my non-ListView strings.

Comment: `listView` is not matched

Comment: @Mike You probably just need to turn on multi line mode.  The pattern is working for me using your website.  Clicks the "flags" button on the upper left to see which flags you might need to enable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That was it! Thanks. Now to test and see if the software I'm using likes it...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's my plan - wanted to test in the actual software first to see if it had issues. Upvoted now and will circle back to mark best once I've run the test :)

Comment: Fair enough...ping me if my pattern gives you a problem, and maybe we can change it if necessary.